# Meaning when linux filename autocomplete ends with 'invisible' "\ "?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, file-extension

Have a file that when viewed in the graphical file explorer or `ls`ed in a terminal looks like "LLCP2015.ASC", but whenever the terminal autocompletes (via `tab`) a command like `less LLCP2015.ASC` it actually ends up completing looking like

```
"less LLCP2015.ASC\   "
```

Notice the trailing escape character and extra spaces (I say that there are extra spaces because that is where the terminal carrot ends up after the autocomplete). I've never seen this before and am curious if anyone knows what this is and if there are any special considerations then when trying to match this file with a `glob` or `regex`? Thanks.

The file in question is a publiclly available data files that can be downloaded [here](https://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/annual_2016.html) (under Data Files / 2016 BRFSS Data (ASCII)[ZIP]) and I am using `cent os 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means that you file name ends with a space. Try this:

```
ls {file} | wc -c
```

Now count the characters that you see and compare with the count given (minus one to take in account the added linefeed). You can also use:

```
ls {file} | hexdump -C

ls somefilespace.txt\  | hexdump -C
00000000  73 6f 6d 65 66 69 6c 65  73 70 61 63 65 2e 74 78  |somefilespace.tx|
00000010  74 20 0a                                          |t .|
```

The `20` is the trailing space. The `0a` is just the LF added by `ls` and not part of the file name,